# Setting Char variables

Tags: c++, variables, char

For a char variable would i also set it to 0 as i would set and int or a float or any other variable?

Such as

```
char test = 0
```

would it be like that since

```
int test = 0
```

would be like that?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? What are you going to do with it after you "clear" it? Store another value? Print it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which do you want? The character '0', or the ascii 0?

If you want to set it to the character '0', then you need:

```
char test = '0';
```

If you want the ascii value 0, then it's fine the way it is.

Comment: I just want it to be cleared with nothing. Basically as int would be 0 yeah.

Comment: Variables don't really need to be "cleared". If you're going to write to it on the first use, you don't need to initialize it to anything.

Comment: More strongly, char and int values cannot be cleared, they always contain a valid value.

Comment: So i can literally use `char test;` and thats it?

Comment: Correct. It doesn't need to be initialized.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - While I agree with you that the value is most certainly *valid* when you declare a variable, it's undetermined.

Comment: So for finding errors with uninitialized data, it is sometimes a good idea to set every variable to a recognizable pattern

Comment: @brian I didn't say it should not be initialized, I said it cannot be cleared. It cannot contain nothing. Clearly variables must be initialized before use.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use type conversions in c++,
so even if you write int test = 0
you can access its ascii by converting it into char,
this goes without saying for chars